# How do you pop modes twice/pop without consuming

Tags: antlr, antlr4

This is an example of the input:

```
<span class="hello">cont@(Property)ent</span>
```

And this is an example of my current grammar (simplified; if there are syntax errors it is because of my written simplification):

```
TAG_OPEN
  : '<' -> pushMode(TAG_MODE)
  ;

mode TAG_MODE;

TAG_CLOSE
  : '>' -> popMode
  ;

TAG_EQUALS
  : '=' -> pushMode(ATTRIBUTE_MODE)
  ;

mode ATTRIBUTE_MODE;

ATTRIBUTE_OPEN
  : '"' -> pushMode(ATTRIBUTE_CONTENT_MODE)
  ;

mode ATTRIBUTE_CONTENT_MODE;

// Code removed that deals with the matching of the @(Property)

ATTRIBUTE_CLOSE
  : '"' -> popMode
  ;

ATTRIBUTE_CONTENT
  : ~["]* // Simplified
  ;
```

Which in a perfectly fine way matches the tag and its attribute, with the open + content + close of the quoted string.
But then it can match no more, since (or so I believe the case is) we're stuck inside the *ATTRIBUTE_MODE* and can't get back to the *TAG_MODE* since the **"** character has been consumed and there is no possible match in *ATTRIBUTE_MODE* for **>**

So I get error message: "token recognition error at: '>'"

And no, I cannot simply match the whole string as one symbol with something like:

```
DOUBLE_QUOTE_STRING
  : '"' ~[<"]* '"'
  ;
```

Since I have to separately match the *@(Property)* of the input. It must be a separate token from the attribute content inside the quoted string.

**So my question is:**
Is there any way to pop several modes? What I'm looking for is something like:

```
ATTRIBUTE_CLOSE
  : '"' -> popMode(2)
  ;
```

or

```
ATTRIBUTE_CLOSE
  : '"' -> popMode, skipButDoNotConsumeCurrentCharacter
  ;
```

"skip" does not work here, since it consumes and continues until the next match. And then I'd attempt someway to pop from *ATTRIBUTE_MODE* to *TAG_MODE* somehow.

Or have I designed this completely wrong from the start?

Thanks for any help/advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to perform a double pop, you can just do:

```
ATTRIBUTE_CLOSE 
 : '"' -> popMode, popMode 
 ;
```